# Pure Stohastic Gradient Descent scaling anomaly

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I train linear regression (y = b0 + b1 * x) with SGD, batch_size=1 and one data pass (epoch). It converges when scaling the input to unreasonable values (see below). When scaling to "standard" values (calculating unit variance and mean on the input dataset) I cannot get convergence to any reasonable error value, no matter how I change learninig rate/iterations. Both x and y are divided to scale_ and centered to mean_.

Training data:
x = [1 .. 70] y = [15.39 ... 356.76]

Standard scaling:
iterations = 500 learning_rate=0.00003
x.scale_ [ 20.20519735] x.mean_ [ 35.5] y.scale_ [ 100.3283148] y.mean_ [ 187.43898263]

[image]

Abnoraml scaling: iterations=500 learning_rate=0.001 x.scale_ [ 2.5] x.mean_ [ 2.5] y.scale_ [ 3.] y.mean_ [ 3.]

[image]

You can see that the learning rate is adjusted according to the scales quotient, so this is not just a learning rate problem (I've tried different values as well).

Comment: The second one looks fine. What values are you expecting? Are you training against logloss?

Comment: Training against OLS. Please look at the input values and standardization parameters. The question is why it diverges with standardized input and converges with randomly scaled input??

Comment: Both seem to behave normally, as in, the loss is decreasing?

Comment: The first one reached value 35 at the end of epoch. As you see 35 is no way reasonable error, when max(x) is 70.

Comment: You could train it for a little longer. If you are using learning rate decay, then you might want to tune that also.

Comment: I use constant rate and increasing iterations number doesn't help as well as increasing points number.